# Problem with document.querySelectorAll; a[href=]' is not a valid selector

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to search the document using:

```
document.querySelectorAll("a[href*=google.com]")[0].href;
```

To search the document for a href containing the google.com URL
The strange thing is that it has always worked for me to this day
What will have happened?
This is the error that shows me:

```
Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'querySelectorAll' on 'Document': 'a[href=google.com]' is not a valid selector.
at <anonymous>:1:10
```

I repeat, I have been using that code for years and today it has stopped working, any solution please?

this is my HTML:

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <title> MY WEB </title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <a rel="nofollow" href="//www.google.com/" target="_blank">GOOGLE</a>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Whenever the value in an attribute selector contains problematic characters (like `.,;:+-*/` etc.), you must quote the attribute value. This does not only apply for CSS attribute selectors, but also for the HTML attribute on the HTML element.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add quote '' to google.com value

```
let result = document.querySelectorAll("a[href*='google.com']")[0].href;
```

```js
let result = document.querySelectorAll("a[href*='google.com']")[0].href;
console.log(result)
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<title> MY WEB </title>
</head>
<body>
<a rel="nofollow" href="//www.google.com/" target="_blank">GOOGLE</a>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try it this way

```
document.querySelectorAll('a[href*="google.com"]')[0].href;
```

You will need to specify the `attribute value` as `string`.

Answer (score 1):

The following demo features 3 ways to reference a link or a group of links.  Details are commented in demo.

In regards to the OP's accepted answer: `.querySelectorAll(...)[0]` is correct but it should be noted that there's a more appropriate answer

```
document.querySelector()                  document.querySelectorAll()
/*
Will find only the first match            Will collect all matches into a NodeList
Returns that match                        Returns the NodeList
```

We can take an educated guess as to which one is faster. In a simple test consisting of only a [single link](https://jsbench.me/crjxeam1qf) -- `qSA[0]` is 37% slower than `qS` and 60% slowe in a test with [10 links](https://jsbench.me/0ljxeb0wqk)

```js
/* #1 
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
If we have ONLY ONE link with href='https://google.com'
OR want ONLY THE FIRST link with href='https://google.com'
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
.querySelector() OR .querySelectorAll()[0] 
*/
document.querySelector("a[href='https://google.com']").style.fontSize = '1.5rem';
document.querySelectorAll("a[href='https://google.com']")[0].style.backgroundColor = 'black';

/* #2
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
If we want ALL OF THE LINKS with href='https://google.com'
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
Collect nodes into a NodeList with .querySelectorAll() 
Iterate through NodeList with `.forEach()`
*/
const gLinx = document.querySelectorAll("a[href='https://google.com']");
gLinx.forEach(node => node.style.color = 'tomato');

/* #3
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
If we want to have A REFERENCE TO ALL LINKS and get all
links with href='https://google.com' right now
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
Collect all <a>nchors into a HTML Collection using .links 
Iterate through collection of links with for...of loop
On each iteration
Compare current value to target selector with .matches()
*/
const allLinx = document.links;

for (let link of allLinx) {
  if (link.matches("a[href='https://google.com']")) {
    let txt = link.textContent;
    link.textContent = txt.toUpperCase();
  }
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ol>
    <li><a href='https://stackoverflow.com'>StackOverflow</a></li>
    <li><a href='https://google.com'>Google</a></li>
    <li><a href='https://google.com'>Google</a></li>
    <li><a href='https://stackoverflow.com'>StackOverflow</a></li>
    <li><a href='https://google.com'>Google</a></li>
    <li><a href='https://stackoverflow.com'>StackOverflow</a></li>
    <li><a href='https://stackoverflow.com'>StackOverflow</a></li>
    <li><a href='https://google.com'>Google</a></li>
  </ol>
</nav>
```